# How to use RapidAPI with VBA Excel (WhoIs Domain Name)

Tags: json, excel, vba, api

I have found some other posts regarding the same subject but there's no clear information or not answered, so I'd be grateful if someone can help me with this issue.

I am using RapidAPI on my VBA code in excel but can't get it working, that's cracking my head. I am trying to retrieve WhoIs information from domain names listed on colum A and the API answer should go on column B. Can anyone give me a light?

Source: https://rapidapi.com/jsonwhois.com/api/json-whois-screenshots-google-social-data/

```
Function GetWhoIs(DomainName As String)
    Dim json, Url, params As String
    Dim jsonObject, objHTTP, strResult, objetoJson As Object
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    Url = "https://jsonwhois.p.rapidapi.com/api/v1/whois/"
    objHTTP.Open "GET", Url, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "authorization", "Token token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "x-rapidapi-host", "jsonwhois.p.rapidapi.com"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "x-rapidapi-key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    params = "domain=" + DomainName
    objHTTP.Send (params)
    strResult = objHTTP.responseText
    json = strResult
    Set objetoJson = JsonConverter.ParseJson(json)
    GetWhoIs objetoJson
End Function

Sub combine()
    Dim a As String
    For Each a In Range("A2:A50")
        If Not IsEmpty(a.Value) Then
            Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = GetWhoIs(a.Value)
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: What errors do you get ?

Comment: I am getting "ByRef argument type mismatch" on "GetWhoIs objetoJson" inside function. But in fact I dont know how to fix it, I already tried a lot of thing and got no results.

Comment: On which line do you get that error? Always helps t provide details on the specific problem you're having with your code.  FYI in VBA if you have a comma-separated list of variables with `... As XXX` at the end - only the last variable gets that XXX type: everything else is Variant.

Comment: `GetWhoIs objetoJson` is calling the function recursively passing the object as a parameter whereas the function expects a string. You probably want to remove that line and change the one above to `Set GetWhoIs= JsonConverter.ParseJson(json)`. However you can't write the object to the sheet you need to extract the data from it you want. To do that you need to know the structure of the Jason string.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a GET, but also sending data in the request body - that is typically only done in a POST operation. For a GET is should really be in the URL querystring.

```
Url = "https://jsonwhois.p.rapidapi.com/api/v1/social?domain=" & DomainName
```

and remove the `(params)` from the `.Send` line –

Comment: I followed your suggestion but still not working. I am getting "ByRef argument type mismatch" on "GetWhoIs objetoJson" inside function. Any idea?